# How do I generate multiple new HTML tags in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a small practice program involving the classic "FizzBuzz" coding problem.  My goal is to have a user input two numbers and have the Fizz's, Buzz's, and FizzBuzz's print to the screen along with the numbers that don't get assigned those particular words.

I've written a function that can take in the user's number and run them through to output the numbers and words.  It may not be pretty but it works.  I've tested it in the console.  What I'm trying to do now is print the output to the screen.  I'm creating `<li>`tags via javascript and appending text to them.  Then I'm appending that list item to the already existing `<ul>` in the `html` document.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="main-container" id="main-container">

        <h1 class="title" id="title">Fizz Buzz</h1>

        <!-- first form container -->
        <div class="first-multiple-container" id="first-multiple-container">

            <h3 class="first-multiple-title" id="first-multiple-title">Enter First Multiple</h3>
            <textarea  id="text-area-1" rows="2" cols="10"></textarea>
        </div>

        <!-- second form container -->
        <div class="second-multiple-container" id="second-multiple-container">

            <h3 class="second-multiple-title" id="second-multiple-title">Enter Second Multiple</h3>
            <textarea  id="text-area-2" rows="2" cols="10"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id="button-container">
          <div id="button">Print Values</div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <ul id="output"></ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

This is my Javascript code

```
const text1 = document.getElementById('text-area-1');
const text2 = document.getElementById('text-area-2');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const list = document.createElement('li');


function findValue(event, num1, num2) {

  let i = 1;

  while (i <= 30) {
    if (i % num1 == 0 && i % num2 == 0) {

      list.appendChild(document.createTextNode('FizzBuzz '));
      output.appendChild(list);

    } else if (i % num1 == 0) {

      list.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Fizz '));
      output.appendChild(list);

    } else if (i % num2 == 0) {

      list.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Buzz '));
      output.appendChild(list);

    } else {
      list.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + ' '));
      output.appendChild(list);
    }

    i++;
  }
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    findValue(evt, text1.value, text2.value);
  });
```

This code is working in the sense that it is printing all the proper output to the screen, but its all inside one `<li>` tag.  So its just one long horizontal line of numbers and words.  I'm assuming this is happening because I'm only creating one `<li>` tag and everything is getting appended into that.

Is there a way to either create new `<li>` tags for every word or number? Or possibly break the line after every space?  I'd like the output to be listed in a single vertical line rather than one long horizontal one.

Comment: Try to create a textnode with a line break instead, like this:

`document.createTextNode('FizzBuzz \n');`

Comment: Adding `\n` would probably work, but from an HTML perspective, it would be better to have each name or number in its own `<li>` tag.  This will also make it easier to style if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the issue is that you are only creating a single `<li>` tag and then appending each word or number to it.  I have modified your code to create a new `<li>` tag for each generated word or number:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const text1 = document.getElementById('text-area-1');
        const text2 = document.getElementById('text-area-2');
        let output = document.getElementById('output');


        function findValue(event, num1, num2) {

            let i = 1,
                list;

            while (i <= 30) {
                if (i % num1 == 0 && i % num2 == 0) {
                    list = document.createElement('li');
                    list.innerHTML = 'FizzBuzz ';
                    output.appendChild(list);
                } else if (i % num1 == 0) {
                    list = document.createElement('li');
                    list.innerHTML = 'Fizz ';
                    output.appendChild(list);
                } else if (i % num2 == 0) {
                    list = document.createElement('li');
                    list.innerHTML = 'Buzz ';
                    output.appendChild(list);
                } else {
                    list = document.createElement('li');
                    list.innerHTML = i + ' ';
                    output.appendChild(list);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
            findValue(evt, text1.value, text2.value);
        });
    });
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="main-container" id="main-container">
        <h1 class="title" id="title">Fizz Buzz</h1>
        <!-- first form container -->
        <div class="first-multiple-container" id="first-multiple-container">
            <h3 class="first-multiple-title" id="first-multiple-title">Enter First Multiple</h3>
            <textarea id="text-area-1" rows="2" cols="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <!-- second form container -->
        <div class="second-multiple-container" id="second-multiple-container">
            <h3 class="second-multiple-title" id="second-multiple-title">Enter Second Multiple</h3>
            <textarea id="text-area-2" rows="2" cols="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="button-container">
            <button id="button">Print Values</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul id="output"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

For the above demo, I turned the #button from a `<div>` into a `<button>` to make it a little easier to tell you are supposed to click it.

The while loop could be futhor simplified like this:

```js
while (i <= 30) {
    list = document.createElement('li');
    if (i % num1 == 0 && i % num2 == 0) {
        list.innerHTML = 'FizzBuzz ';
    } else if (i % num1 == 0) {
        list.innerHTML = 'Fizz ';
    } else if (i % num2 == 0) {
        list.innerHTML = 'Buzz ';
    } else {
        list.innerHTML = i + ' ';
    }
    output.appendChild(list);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  So the new `<li>` gets created every time and If/else chunk runs.  Its so simple. Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  A new `<li>` element gets created in each loop of the while loop and then get appended to the `<ul>` element.  After I posted my answer I realized that the while loop could be simplified even more, so I updated my answer to include a code snippet showing an even simpler while loop.